# pivot query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm trying for the first time in my life to use the PIVOT on my database table.
This is the table:

```
Answers (id_user, id_question, topic, value) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a', 3),
(1, 1, 'b', 3),
(1, 1, 'c', 2),

(1, 2, 'a', 1),
(1, 2, 'b', 2),
(1, 2, 'c', 3),

[...]

(1, 14, 'a', 1),
(1, 14, 'b', 2),
(1, 14, 'c', 1);
```

But I'm trying to get to this:

```
Answers (id_user, id_question, topic_A, topic_B, topic_C) VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 3, 2),
(1, 2, 1, 2, 3),
[...]
(1, 14, 1, 2, 1);
```

with this query I get a generic syntax ERROR near PIVOT

```
SELECT *
FROM
(     SELECT id_user, id_question, topic, value
      FROM Answers
      WHERE id_user=98
) as risp
PIVOT 
(     FOR id_question IN ([a],[b],[c])
)     AS pvt
```

Comment: MySQL has no `PIVOT` query for what I know.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, right - the `PIVOT` syntax is for Microsoft SQL Server, and it's not supported by other SQL implementations.

Comment: there's other approach to do this?
edit: thank you for the answer, I'm watching the post you have linked

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Oracle 11g also supports `pivot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way todo this in MySQL using aggregation:

```
select id_user, id_question,
       max(case when topic = 'A' then value end) as topic_A,
       max(case when topic = 'B' then value end) as topic_B,
       max(case when topic = 'C' then value end) as topic_C
from Answers a
group by id_user, id_question;
```

By the way, it wouldn't be reasonable to put this back into the same table.  The query should be sufficient.  You can also put this into a view or into another table.

EDIT:

An alternative approach is to use joins.  The query is a bit more complicated:

```
select uq.id_user, uq.id_question, aa.value as topic_A,
       ab.value as topic_B, ac.value as topic_C
from (select distinct id_user, id_question from answers) uq left outer join
     Answers aa
     on aa.id_user = uq.id_user and aa.id_question = uq.id_question and
        aa.topic = 'A' left outer join
     Answers ab
     on ab.id_user = uq.id_user and ab.id_question = uq.id_question and
        ab.topic = 'B' left outer join
     Answers aa
     on ac.id_user = uq.id_user and ac.id_question = uq.id_question and
        ac.topic = 'C';
```

Comment: the first query works great, instead the second doesn't work. no result, phpmyadmin reloads the page without show nothing.
however, the first it's perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: @user3160178 . . . I prefer the first version anyway.