# pivot query doesn't execute on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

in reference to this  [[pivot article]](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)
I managed to get this prepared pivot query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(IF(name = ''',
     name,
      ''', 1, NULL)) AS ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM bundles;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM bundles');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and here's a live demo [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e410/1)

the problem is when I try to execute that on my data with the same schema using mysql(5.6.14 Win32 x86) I get an error.

> Error
>   SQL query:
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
>
> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 -

just an error code but no message..
I've read SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406520/pivot-query-doesnt-work) but the answers are the static way which won't work with unknown columns
first of all, is this even available in mysql?? .. any pointers are appreciated

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM bundles` would return a single-quote/apostrophe or other undesirable character?  Here's a counter-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8276f/1 which produces a similar error.

Comment: @ebyrob actually I get the error when I execute the procedure

Comment: My point was, I think you may have a single quote `'` in that `name` column in `bundles`.  That would certainly invalidate the syntax of the dynamic query you're building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema may be the same, but your data is probably different.  You may have a keyword, space, or something else in your values which is causing the issue.  Try to wrap your alias in double quotes.

Here's my edit to your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e410/5).  I added a line which outputs the dynamic SQL in case you need to examine what you get on your system with your data.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(IF(name = ''',
     name,
      ''', 1, NULL)) AS "',
      name, '"'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM bundles;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM bundles');
SELECT CONCAT(@sql);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```